# While executing test case from grid I am getting error as org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException, entire error is given in the description

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid

org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create session from
"desiredCapabilities": {
"server:CONFIG_UUID": "41384e57-d3e3-41a0-bbe1-1dccb9df5e3d"
}

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create session from {
  "desiredCapabilities": {
    "server:CONFIG_UUID": "41384e57-d3e3-41a0-bbe1-1dccb9df5e3d"
  },
  "capabilities": {
    "firstMatch": [
      {
        "server:CONFIG_UUID": "41384e57-d3e3-41a0-bbe1-1dccb9df5e3d"
      }
    ]
  }
}
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-0NT3ARK', ip: 'ip' os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '16.0.1'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown

Comment: probably check your driver version and browser version

Comment: @cruisepandey- All are good before implementing grid all was fine and smooth and working fine, after implementation of grid also it was smooth, it started not working once added data layer in the project.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is once after defining the desired capabilities we have to merge with browser specific options class, like

ChromeOptions opt = new ChromeOptions();
opt.merge(cap);

then the above error will not come.